# GWT cache config via Apache 2.2 httpd.conf?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, gwt, httpd.conf

The GWT perfect caching documntation (http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#perfect_caching) suggests to add the following lines to my .htaccess file:

```
<Files *.nocache.*>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "now"
    Header merge Cache-Control "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
</Files>

<Files *.cache.*>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 year"
</Files>
```

As I'm not using .htaccess files but have access to the Apache 2.2 httpd.conf file I would prefer to add those lines there.

But where / how?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for the [`<Files>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files) directive clearly states where you can use it:

> Context:  server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess

In most cases, you'd probably want to add it to your application's [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost) (if you want the caching rules to apply only to that application) or the server's config (outside any directive, usually in httpd.conf) - if you want to apply those rules globally (useful if you have more than one GWT application on the server).

If you want to use it in a virtual host directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName host.example.com

    #...

    <Files *.nocache.*>
        ExpiresActive on
        ExpiresDefault "now"
        Header merge Cache-Control "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    </Files>

    <Files *.cache.*>
        ExpiresActive on
        ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 year"
    </Files>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you want to use them globally, just put them in httpd.conf, outside of any directives.